# Using python to subtract an nx1 array (matrix) from a nxm array (matrix)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have the following code:

```
X = np.array([[2,2,2,4,5,6],[1,2,3,3,3,4]])

mu = np.mean(X,axis=1)
```

**My Problem:**

When I try to subtract the mean from the data (`X` - `mu`), I get the following error:
`operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,6) (2,)`
This makes sense but still having trouble trying to subtract the mean from this data, X. I am expecting the following result:

```
1.5 1.5 1.5 0.5 1.5 2.5
1.67 0.67 0.33 0.33 0.33 1.33
```

Comment: Reshape `mu` into something with shape `(2,1)`. Easiest way to do calculate `X - mu` would be something like `X - mu[:,None]`.

Comment: Thanks @droooze. Would you mind explaining what the [:,None] means in the mu[:,None] statement or pointing me to a resource where I can learn myself. Really appreciate it.

Comment: The documentation for the syntax is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange), although I don't think it's very clear. Basically, `mu[:,None]` preserves the data structure where `:` is and inserts a new axis at the position where `None` is given, so your first axis of `mu` is untouched (original shape is `(2,)`) but a new dimension of size `1` is inserted at the second axis. I may have confused you further with this explanation, so it's best to try with multidimensional arrays and inserting `None` to see the behaviour.

Comment: That's not nx1; there's no length-1 second axis on `mu`.

Answer (score 1):

```
X = np.array([[2,2,2,4,5,6],[1,2,3,3,3,4]])
mu = np.mean(X,axis=1).reshape((2,1))
X-mu
```

However, this does not yield the result that you are expecting but:

```
[[-1.5,-1.5,-1.5,0.5,1.5,2.5],
[-1.66666667, -0.66666667,  0.33333333,  0.33333333,  0.33333333,1.33333333]]
```

which is correct in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [162]: X = np.array([[2,2,2,4,5,6],[1,2,3,3,3,4]])
```

`mu` is not 2x1, it is (2,), 1d.

```
In [163]: mu = np.mean(X,axis=1)
In [164]: mu.shape
Out[164]: (2,)
```

To subtract that from a (2,6) you have turn it into a (2,1) array.  `mu[:,None]` does that as does `reshape`.

Another option is to ask `mean` to `keepdims`:

```
In [165]: mu = np.mean(X,axis=1,keepdims=True)
In [166]: mu.shape
Out[166]: (2, 1)
In [167]: X-mu
Out[167]: 
array([[-1.5       , -1.5       , -1.5       ,  0.5       ,  1.5       ,
         2.5       ],
       [-1.66666667, -0.66666667,  0.33333333,  0.33333333,  0.33333333,
         1.33333333]])
```